# Erro ao passar variável

Tags: php

Estou tentando passar uma variável, mas ela não aparece na tela.

O erro...

Notice: Undefined index: operador_mapa in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema\Views\form_mapa_continua.php on line 58

Aqui está onde eu chamo a função:

```
$nome = $busca_mapas->busca_mapa($id);
```

Aqui está a função:

```
public function busca_mapa($id){
    $conexao = Database::getConnection();

    $busca = "SELECT * from mapa WHERE cod_mapa = $id;";
    $mapa = $conexao->query($busca);
    $retorno = $mapa->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $retorno;

}
```

Aqui está o código html onde eu imprimo a variável (e é onde, também, o erro aparece):

```
<div class="disabled field">
    <label>Nome do operador</label>
       <input value="<?= $nome['operador_mapa'];?>" placeholder="<?=$nome['operador_mapa']?>">
</div>
```

O banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Posso garantir a vocês que há dados no banco.

Comment: Consegue dar um var_dump na varável $nome e postar aqui o resultado por favor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você utilizou o [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php), que retorna um *array* de resultados. Como está buscando pelo id, terá sempre apenas um resultado, fazendo com que `$nome` fique semelhante a:

```
$nome = [
    0 => [
        'setor_mapa' => ...,
        'operador_mapa' => ...,
        ...
    ]
];
```

Assim, para exibir um valor, seria necessário `$nome[0]['operador_mapa']`; ou você usa o método [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php), que já retorna o resultado.

Comment: Nossa, resolveu!!! Obrigada! :)